# If a length is 1 and then it's elevated to two then what is it?

Tags: computer-science, computability

If $x=1$, then that means that $x^2 = 1$, also. Is the case the same if it has to do with lengths? That's if I got the $|x| = 1$ and then I raised to the power of two so $|x|^2= ...$ will it then be 2 or 1? I'm thinking as it has to do with length it might be addition instead of multiplication.

Where x is the length of a string.

A string is for example "abc" and it has the length 3, because it has 3 symbols in it. "a" has the length 1. So I'm wondering if |x| = |"a"|=1 then will |x|^2 be |"aa"|=2 or will it still be |"a"|=1.

Comment: What does it mean to "multiply" lengths together? Is $x$ in this context, say, a vector?

Comment: x is a length of a string. @EeveeTrainer

Comment: Okay but that doesn't answer my first, arguably more important, question. For example if I had two strings of lengths $5$ meters each, what would multiplying them even truly "mean"? The immediate idea that comes to mind is that $5 m \times 5 m = 25 m^2$, but that's an area, not a length, for example, so I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: By "elevated to two", do you main "raised to the power of two"?  Also known as "squared".

Comment: A string is for example "abc" and it has the length 3, because it has 3 symbols in it. "a" has the length 1. So I'm wondering if |x| = |"a"|=1 then will |x|^2 be |"aa"|=2 or will it still be |"a"|=1.@EeveeTrainer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|x|$ is a number and squaring a number is a well defined and known operation. If $|x|=1$, then squaring the *length* of $x$ results again to 1, since $|x|^2 =1^2 = 1$.

Squaring the length of the string is not an operation on the string itself, but on its length.

The transformation that you describe in you example (from '$a$' to '$aa$') is a *concatenation* of two same strings '$a$' and '$a$'. In general, if $x$ and $y$ are strings with $|x|=n$ and $|y|=m$, then you can define a new string, $xy$ which is the concatenation of the two (writing first $x$ and then $y$ right after, without any separators, is the new string). The length of the new string, then, is $m + n$. For your example, consider $x = y =$ '$a$'.

In summary, for some string $x$ with $|x| = n$, we have $$|x|^2 = n^2$$ If by $x^2$ you mean $xx$, then also we have $$|x^2| = |xx| = 2|x| = 2n$$

Note that in the first case squaring is outside the bars ($|x|^2$), while in the second case the "squaring" notation (which actually denotes concatenation) is inside the bars ($|x^2|$).